# Idle resident instances does nothing for minutes

Tags: google-app-engine

I was surprised to find that idle instances of google app engine does nothing to serve any new requests but dynamic instances handled most of them. Many idle instances are **actually idle** for some minutes.. Even I check logs but nothing left.

[image]

Here is my application settings.

[image]

Why dynamic instances does more be scheduled than idle ones? How can I improve my settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idle instances are "reserve" instances so that when **increase in traffic** happens they are immediately available. This is what docs say: `Idle Instances are pre-loaded with your application code, so when a new Instance is needed, it can serve traffic immediately.`

So you need to have a large number of idle instances only if you expect large traffic spikes, but only if you want to keep the same latency.

Here is the calculation: instance can handle (up to) 10 req/s and it takes 15 sec to spin up. So if you expect traffic increases of 10 req/s within 15 sec period you only need one idle instance, if it's an increase of 30 req/s you need two, etc..